# Flutter Aplicación no instalada

Tags: android-studio, flutter, apk, build.gradle

mi problema es que siempre he pasado la app-debug.apk a otras personas para que prueben la aplicación en sus teléfonos sin problema.
La cojo de aquí: \build\app\outputs\flutter-apk

Pues bien, el lunes esto funcionaba sin problema, pero el miércoles al ir a hacer lo mismo que hacía siempre no se instala en el teléfono. En esos días no actualicé Android Studio ni cambié el pubspec.yaml ni nada relevante. He intentado volver a la versión de mi proyecto del lunes y hacer el proceso de siempre pero tampoco funciona ya.

No aparece ningún error, sólo se ve esto:
[image: Primera pantalla de instalación]
[image: Aplicación no instalada]

Al investigar qué podía pasar he visto que en el build.gradle hay errores:

- Cannot resolve symbol Properties
- Cannot resolve symbol GradleException
- Cannot resolve symbol FileInputStream

[image: Errores build.gradle]

Supongo que es por esto que no funciona la apk. He probado Invalidate caches and Restart que es lo que he leído por ahí y nada.

Desde Android Studio la app corre perfectamente tanto en el emulador como en mi teléfono.

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Comment: podrías indicar que errores salen al instalar?

Comment: No sale ningún error al instalar, sólo se ve la pantalla que acabo de subir a la pregunta

Comment: Probaste con desinstalar por completo la app y instalar desde cero con el apk? Tambien podes ejecutar un "flutter clean" y volver a compilar la app para que se regenere el apk.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema? Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 0):

Si llegan hasta este post, porque instalan la app y aparece el icono pero al clicar en el sale un contradictorio mensaje que indica "App no instalada", deben verificar que en el AndroidManifest.xml el atributo exported del main activity sea true, ejemplo

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:exported="true"
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).